# Can Pastebin.com turn URLs into clickable links?

Tags: links, url, pastebin

Is [Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) capable of turning URLs into clickable links? Is not there additional markup code for this besides [`@h@`](http://pastebin.com/faq#13) for line highlighting?

[This discussion](http://www.blackhatworld.com/blackhat-seo/white-hat-seo/472007-clickable-links-pastebin.html) suggests that it is not possible. I also searched available documentation without success.

Alternatively, which similar services support clickable URLs?

Answer (score 7):

This is a little late, but [Pastelink.net](http://pastelink.net) should do what you're looking for.

Comment: https://pastelink.net is essentially what OP is looking for, a service similar to Pastebin.com which allows clickable hyperlinks.

Comment: @pnuts ...that's not a link to an answer, that link **is** his answer. I think you're confused about the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ipaste](http://www.ipaste.eu/), for instance: http://www.ipaste.eu/view?id=5172

Comment: Looks like ipaste doesn't exist anymore